# Aframe double vision on Gear VR with stereo

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have a strange issue on aframe on Samsung Gear VR (in Chrome via a Cordova app).

Generally everything is fine until I load stereo video using the [stereo component](https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component)

Here the video is fine, however the cursor and any other 3D elements in the scene show double in the VR headset.

You can see in this screenshot that the cursor , text and pause button are not in alignment with the man behind, i.e. the the cursor on the right is on his shirt. 
That is partly because of the stereo effect, but if there is no stereo effect the cursor and other 3D elements line up and are clear in a headset. With the stereo effect they are all doubled in the headset.

[image]

The cursor is here

```
        {/* Camera */}
    <Entity rotation={defaultCameraRotation}>
      <Entity primitive='a-camera' id='camera'  mouse-zoom wasd-controls={wasdControls} stereocam="eye:left">
        {
          isVrEnabled &&
          <Entity position="0 0 -1"
            geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.026;"
            material={cursorMaterial}
            scale={cursorFuseScale}
            cursor={cursorAttributes}>
            <a-animation {...cursorClickAnimation} />
            <a-animation {...cursorFuseAnimation} />
            <Entity position="0 0 0"
              geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.01; radiusOuter: 0.015;"
              material="color:white; shader: flat; opacity:0.7;"/>
          </Entity> 
        } 
      </Entity>
    </Entity>
```

It doesn't have this problem if you look to the side or back, only when facing the 3D video.i.e. if you turn to the side and look at the edge, the cursor lines up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a browser with native WebVR support like Oculus Browser or Samsung Internet. Polyfilled WebVR won’t work well in Gear VR. Unfortunately, It doesn’t seem that Cordova is WebVR compatible.

Chrome ships WebVR but only on [daydream-ready phones](https://vr.google.com/daydream/smartphonevr/phones/) and does not support GearVR. If you have a Samsung S8 / S9 and a daydream view you can enable WebVR in `chrome://flags` and stereo alignment should be correct.

Comment: The stereo component works really well.. shows great 3D video!?

Comment: Cordova runs with Chrome - I've not had a problem with WebVR?

Comment: The video is a sphere far away not affected by perspective. Misalignments, wrong IPD or distortion are less or not noticeable.

Comment: Chrome doesn’t support Gear VR. Chrome for Android does have WebVR but disabled by default. As far as I know Cordova also ships with older versions (not latest Chrome)

Comment: Ah.. ok. So everything else that is closer needs to have those attributes applied

Comment: Exactly the same thing is happening in Chrome as a browser as well

Comment: If I'm not running WebVR I must just be running WebGL right, - because everything runs fine in Chrome via Cordova, exactly the same as Chrome on it's own.

Comment: Chrome does not have WebVR unless you enable it in chrome://flags and that’s only in Pixel 1 / Pixel 2 phones that are Daydream compatible.

Comment: Right thanks. Are you saying WebVR will fix this issue tho, or is there anyway to apply the data via another method?

Comment: In GearVR you are out of luck. On an Android phone with a Cardboard holder your scene should work via polyfill. What phone are you using?

Comment: Does your scene run as expected on the Oculus Browser for Gear VR?

Comment: The GearVR app is running Chome. The scene runs fine on an Android phone with cardboard and it also runs fine on the GearVR app. The issue is exactly the same on both.

Comment: There is a problem with the Oculus Browser, one eye is blank. However the cursor lines up OK

Comment: I'm using Cordova to store the files offline to get high res viewing and a few other tricks. I think I might run a small server from the app and open the app in the Samsung Gear or Oculus Browser via the ovr intent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165064/how-to-make-an-app-ready-for-ovrweb-protocol-to-be-viewed-in-gear-vr

Comment: Cordova would be fine if you can get native WebVR support in GearVR

Comment: Cheers yeah I think this is a solution. Using Cordova for the native features I want, i.e. database, offline file storage and using Samsung or Oculus Browser for WebVR. The issue will be starting the browser from the app, but it seems a few people have found a way to do that via the ovr:// intent.